# how can I use two databinding?

Tags: android

I'm using databinding of viewmodel. But also I wanna use databinding of activity or fragment. So I tried to add two binding variable but doesn't work. Already I'm using first binding of ViewModel. So I wrote my Fragment code for this. When I added second binding "fragment" and Call this, I can't refer this. what the problem?? here is my code

```
class HomeFragment() : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel> { viewModelFactory }

    private lateinit var viewDataBinding: FragmentHomeBinding

    companion object {
        var homeFragment: HomeFragment? = null
    }

    fun getInstance(context: Context): HomeFragment {
        if (homeFragment == null) {
            homeFragment = HomeFragment()
        }
        return homeFragment!!
    }



    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        viewDataBinding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        return view
    }


    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewDataBinding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner
        Log.d("TAG","HomeFragment onCreate")
        init()
        viewModel.init()

    }

    private fun init(){

    }




}
```

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.haii.loginproject.fragment.home.HomeViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="fragment"
            type="com.haii.loginproject.fragment.home.HomeFragment" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noticeHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Header" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noticeMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Home Fragment"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/noticeFooter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="Footer" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```